# Can I do academic research while on ESTA?

Tags: esta, j1-visas

This is related to the following topic: [Doing research on ESTA / J-1 visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124576/doing-research-on-esta-j-1-visa).

However, the circumstances are more favorable for me, so that is why I want to ask: I want to conduct research with a professor from a US university. I will be staying in the US for 28 days to do so. My home university will pay for the expenses of this trip, but I will not be given any money for going there; I only receive the scholarship that I regularly receive independently of my location.

As there is no US funding involved, I do not get any salary for going to the US, as the stay is less than 30 days and I will not attend any courses or do any other research in the US after these 28 days, I feel like ESTA is enough. What do you think?

Comment: Are you coming as a tourist? Doesn't sound like it. A business meeting? Seems like a no. So no, ESTA is not enough. The 30 days referred to in the other question is the university guideline, not the US law.

Comment: Technically this would be under the *Visa Waiver Program*; ESTA is just the name of the specific form you use to get permission to travel to the US and ask to be admitted under the Visa Waiver Program.

Comment: @littleadv: Well, in real life, these kind of academic visits are very commonly done under VWP.  "Conducting research with" someone generally boils down to an extended series of meetings with that person, where the topic is your common profession, and so I think most academics characterize them as business meetings.  W-B also allows trainings and independent research, which are pretty similar to this as well. You just want to be careful to avoid the colloquial expression of "I'm coming to work with Professor Smith".

Comment: @NateEldredge well, in real life "don't ask, don't tell" works well... :-D

Comment: If you did want to apply for a J-1 visa, AFAIK you'd have to go through the international office of the host university.  I bet a lot they'll say you don't need one.  In any case I very much doubt they will sponsor one for such a short visit, so your choice is probably down to "use VWP" or "don't go".  If you're really concerned about the consequences then you probably need to be talking to a lawyer and not just the Internet.

Comment: Talk to professor's US university. It won't be the first time they've done this, probably not the first time this week.

Comment: @littleadv academic research is permitted for a business visitor as long as there is no US income and no benefit to a US institution.  See for example [What does the term "benefit" in independent research category, under B-1 visa, imply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104916/19400)